# Sampling one sample from each ID with equal number of samples in each group

Tags: python, r, pandas, sampling

I have a dataset with multiple rows of data for each ID. There are around 5000 IDs, and each ID can have 1 to 22 rows of data, each row belonging to a different group. I want to **sample 1 row from each ID**, and I want the **sampled data to be equally distributed among the groups**.

This is a dummy `df`, which is simplified so that there are 8 IDs, and each ID can have 1 to 4 rows of data:

```
id group
1  a
1  b
1  c
1  d
2  a
2  b
3  a
3  b
3  c
3  d
4  a
4  b
4  d
5  a
5  b
5  c
5  d
6  a
6  d
7  a
7  b
7  d
8  a
8  b
8  c
8  d
```

Since there are 8 IDs and 4 groups, I want the sampled data to have 2 IDs from each group. The number 2 is just because I want an **equal distribution among groups**, so if there are 20 IDs and 4 groups, I would want the sampled data to have 5 IDs from each group. Also, I want to sample one row from each ID, so **all IDs should appear once and only once in the sampled data**. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried using weights in `pd.DataFrame.sample`, using 1/frequency of each group as the weight, hoping that rows in groups with less frequency will have more weight and therefore have higher chance of being sampled, so that the final sampled data would be roughly equally distributed among groups. But it didn't work as I expected. I tried using different random states, but none of them gave me a sampled dataset that was equally distributed among groups. This is the code I used:

```
#Create dummy dataframe:
d = {'id': [1,1,1,1,
              2,2,
              3,3,3,3,
              4,4,4,
              5,5,5,5,
              6,6,
              7,7,7,
              8,8,8,8], 
     'group': ['a','b','c','d',
              'a','b',
              'a','b','c','d',
              'a','b','d',
              'a','b','c','d',
              'a','d',
              'a','b','d',
              'a','b','c','d']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    
#Calculate weights
df['inverted_freq'] = 1./df.groupby('group')['group'].transform('count')
    
#Sample one row from each ID
df1 = df.groupby('id').apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, random_state=1, n=1, weights=df.inverted_freq).reset_index(drop=True)
```

My expected output is:

```
id  group
1   d
2   b
3   a
4   d
5   c
6   a
7   b
8   c
```

or something similar to this, with one row per ID and an equal number of rows per group.

Suggestions in either R or Python would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby(['id', 'group']).sample(n=2)`?

Comment: Thank you, but I think by grouping by id and group, there would only be one row in each group (because there are no rows with duplicate id AND group), so we won't be able to sample from that?

Comment: Now I don't quite understand the problem, are you certain that such a distribution is possible?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if it's possible to get a perfectly equal distribution, but I was hoping for a roughly equal distribution, and I initially thought that could be achieved by setting the weights in the sampling process.

Answer (score 1):

In R, you can use `dplyr::slice_sample`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   slice_sample(n = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, my question might've been unclear. I also want to get only one row of data from each ID, so in the final dataset, each ID would only appear once. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, sample(.I, 2), group]$V1]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, my question might've been unclear. I also want to get only one row of data from each ID, so in the final dataset, each ID would only appear once. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: @natnichateja Perhaps you want want to get the `unique` i.e. `df2 <- unique(setDT(df1)); df2[df2[, sample(.I, 2), group)$V1]`

Comment: This gives me the same output as the previous code. I think it's because there are no rows with duplicate id AND group. And if I'm understanding your approach correctly, I think you are suggesting that I should remove rows with duplicate ids after sampling? Two issues with that are 1. some id will not appear at all in the sampled data (sorry, I might've been unclear about this requirement) and 2. the distribution among groups will change and not be equal anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df.groupby("id").sample(n=2)

    id  group
0   1   a
2   1   c
4   2   a
5   2   b
7   3   b
9   3   d
12  4   d
10  4   a
13  5   a
16  5   d
18  6   d
17  6   a
21  7   d
19  7   a
23  8   b
24  8   c
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, my question might've been unclear. I only want to get one row from each ID, so my final dataset would have 8 rows. And I want those 8 rows to be equally distributed among the 4 groups, so there would be 2 rows in group a, 2 rows in group b, 2 rows in group c, and 2 rows in group d. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: can you add an example of expected output in your question ?